# Writing to a rich text box in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

New programmer here.

I've written an application to filter out password protected files from a large collection. It is working so far...

My problem is that I am trying to get the resulting paths + what happened to them to write out into a text box. Maybe I am missing something completely obvious here, but I am getting the error:

> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field,
> method, or property `MainWindow.SearchRunOutputBox`

when attempting to assign values inside an updater method I wrote.

I am very confused as I had assumed that a rich text box, already present on the form, would be it's own object? Again, maybe I am just missing something obvious here...

Code below:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CircuitBreaker;
using Spire.Pdf.Exporting.XPS.Schema;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Find_Move_PWP_PDF_s
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static void OutputBoxUpdater(string message, Color color)
        {  
            SearchRunOutputBox.SuspendLayout();
            SearchRunOutputBox.SelectionColor = color;
            SearchRunOutputBox.AppendText(message);
            SearchRunOutputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            SearchRunOutputBox.ScrollToCaret();
            SearchRunOutputBox.ResumeLayout();
        }
```

Is the text box object not created when `InitializeComonent()` is called as the `MainWindow` starts?

Included designer.cs below:

```cs
partial class MainWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Label DirectoryPathLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label CreateSubFoldersLabel;
            this.DirectoryPathInput = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SearchStartButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SearchProgressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.MovePDFsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.MovesProgressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.SearchRunOutputBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            DirectoryPathLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            CreateSubFoldersLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // DirectoryPathLabel
            // 
            DirectoryPathLabel.AccessibleDescription = "DirectoryPathLabel";
            DirectoryPathLabel.AutoSize = true;
            DirectoryPathLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            DirectoryPathLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            DirectoryPathLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 23);
            DirectoryPathLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            DirectoryPathLabel.Name = "DirectoryPathLabel";
            DirectoryPathLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(370, 25);
            DirectoryPathLabel.TabIndex = 0;
            DirectoryPathLabel.Text = "Please enter the desired search directory.";
            // 
            // CreateSubFoldersLabel
            // 
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.AccessibleDescription = "CreateSubFoldersLabel";
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.AccessibleName = "CreateSubFoldersLabel";
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.AutoSize = true;
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 453);
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.Name = "CreateSubFoldersLabel";
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(725, 25);
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.TabIndex = 5;
            CreateSubFoldersLabel.Text = "Click here to move the password protected PDFs into subfolders labelled \"Locked\"." +
    "";
            // 
            // DirectoryPathInput
            // 
            this.DirectoryPathInput.AccessibleDescription = "DirectoryPathInput";
            this.DirectoryPathInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(424, 30);
            this.DirectoryPathInput.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.DirectoryPathInput.Name = "DirectoryPathInput";
            this.DirectoryPathInput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(822, 23);
            this.DirectoryPathInput.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // SearchStartButton
            // 
            this.SearchStartButton.AccessibleDescription = "SearchStartButton";
            this.SearchStartButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1278, 23);
            this.SearchStartButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.SearchStartButton.Name = "SearchStartButton";
            this.SearchStartButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(248, 30);
            this.SearchStartButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.SearchStartButton.Text = "Start Search";
            this.SearchStartButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.SearchStartButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SearchStartButton_Click);
            // 
            // SearchProgressBar
            // 
            this.SearchProgressBar.AccessibleDescription = "SearchProgressBar";
            this.SearchProgressBar.AccessibleName = "SearchProgressBar";
            this.SearchProgressBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 257);
            this.SearchProgressBar.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.SearchProgressBar.Name = "SearchProgressBar";
            this.SearchProgressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1512, 15);
            this.SearchProgressBar.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // MovePDFsButton
            // 
            this.MovePDFsButton.AccessibleDescription = "MovePDFsButton";
            this.MovePDFsButton.AccessibleName = "MovePDFsButton";
            this.MovePDFsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(767, 453);
            this.MovePDFsButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.MovePDFsButton.Name = "MovePDFsButton";
            this.MovePDFsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(237, 25);
            this.MovePDFsButton.TabIndex = 6;
            this.MovePDFsButton.Text = "Move PDFs";
            this.MovePDFsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // MovePDFsRunOutputBox
            // 
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.AccessibleDescription = "MovePDFsRunOutputBox";
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.AccessibleName = "MovePDFsRunOutputBox";
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 489);
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.Name = "MovePDFsRunOutputBox";
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.ReadOnly = true;
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1511, 190);
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.TabIndex = 7;
            this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox.Text = "";
            // 
            // MovesProgressBar
            // 
            this.MovesProgressBar.AccessibleDescription = "MovesProgressBar";
            this.MovesProgressBar.AccessibleName = "MovesProgressBar";
            this.MovesProgressBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 687);
            this.MovesProgressBar.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.MovesProgressBar.Name = "MovesProgressBar";
            this.MovesProgressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1512, 15);
            this.MovesProgressBar.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // SearchRunOutputBox
            // 
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.AccessibleDescription = "SearchRunOutputBox";
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.AccessibleName = "SearchRunOutputBox";
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.CausesValidation = false;
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 60);
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.Name = "SearchRunOutputBox";
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.ReadOnly = true;
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1511, 190);
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.TabIndex = 4;
            this.SearchRunOutputBox.Text = "";
            // 
            // MainWindow
            // 
            this.AccessibleDescription = "MainWindow";
            this.AccessibleName = "MainWindow";
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1540, 726);
            this.Controls.Add(this.MovesProgressBar);
            this.Controls.Add(this.MovePDFsRunOutputBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.MovePDFsButton);
            this.Controls.Add(CreateSubFoldersLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.SearchRunOutputBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.SearchProgressBar);
            this.Controls.Add(this.SearchStartButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.DirectoryPathInput);
            this.Controls.Add(DirectoryPathLabel);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.Name = "MainWindow";
            this.Text = "Find and Move Password Protected PDF\'s";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox DirectoryPathInput;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button SearchStartButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar SearchProgressBar;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button MovePDFsButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar MovesProgressBar;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox MovePDFsRunOutputBox;
        public System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox SearchRunOutputBox;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make the text box a static item? Or should I bet using something else to display the log?

I've tried initiating a new text box inside the OutBoxUpdater(), which got rid of the error, but doesn't seem to do anything. Or it did something, but not what I wanted lol.

```cs
public static void OutputBoxUpdater(string message, Color color)
{
    RichTextBox SearchRunOutputBox = new();

    SearchRunOutputBox.SuspendLayout();
    SearchRunOutputBox.SelectionColor = color;
    SearchRunOutputBox.AppendText(message);
    SearchRunOutputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    SearchRunOutputBox.ScrollToCaret();
    SearchRunOutputBox.ResumeLayout();
}
```

**Edit:**

As per the first comment from Steve, and sorry I didn't mention that I had tried this before, when I remove static from the method, it pushes the error down to where I am trying to call the method from.

```cs
using Spire.Pdf;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace Find_Move_PWP_PDF_s
{
    public class PDFOpenToCheck
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Takes in a file path and attempts to open the file, throwing an error if it cannot, then saying it's password protected, and logging the filepath.
        /// Also checks that the file is not empty, and if it is, logs the filepath to a different log.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">Current file path from stack.</param>
        public void TryToOpenPDF(string filePath)
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = new();
            FileInfo fi = new(filePath);

            try
            {
                pdf.LoadFromFile(filePath);
                MainWindow.OutputBoxUpdater(filePath + " successfully opened!", Color.Black);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Not empty and is a PDF
                if (fi.Length > 0 && filePath.EndsWith(".pdf"))
                {
                    MainWindow.OutputBoxUpdater(filePath + " is password protected!", Color.Red);
                    LogWriters.WritePWPPDFLog(filePath);
                }
                //Is an empty file
                else if (fi.Length <= 0)
                {
                    MainWindow.OutputBoxUpdater(filePath + " is an empty file!", Color.Blue);
                    LogWriters.WriteEmptyFileLog(filePath);
                }
                //Is not empty and is not a PDF
                else
                {
                    MainWindow.OutputBoxUpdater(filePath + " is not a PDF!", Color.Green);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

EDIT:
To show where TryToOpenPDF() is being called from.

```
namespace Find_Move_PWP_PDF_s
{
    public static class TraverseDirectoryTree
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Recursive method to iterate through the directory structure below the provided start point.
        /// In this application, will also perform PDF checking with Spire as it iterates (Line 74).
        /// Uses stack based iteration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="root">Starting parent directory.</param>
        public static void TraverseTree(string root)
        {
            // Data structure to hold names of subfolders to be examined for files
            // "Stack<T>" works by "first in last out" and could take a long time to build the initial stack before iteration begins
            Stack<string> dirs = new();

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(root))
            {
                ArgumentException argumentException = new();
                throw argumentException;
            }
            dirs.Push(root);

            while (dirs.Count > 0)
            {
                string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
                string[] subDirs;
                try
                {
                    subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
                }
                // "Unauthorized Access Exception" will be thrown if we do not have discovery permission on a folder or file. 
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                }
                //"Directory Not Found Exception" will be thrown if currentDir has been deleted by another application or thread after our call to Directory
                catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                }

                string[]? files;
                try
                {
                    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);
                }

                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                }

                catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                }
                // Perform the required action on each file here
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PDFOpenToCheck.TryToOpenPDF(file);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        // If file was deleted by a separate application or thread since the call to "TraverseTree()", then just continue.
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }

                // Push the subdirectories onto the stack for traversal
                foreach (string str in subDirs)
                    dirs.Push(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When a method is declared as _public static_  it doesn't have an instance of the class in which is declared to work with. It belongs to the class itself. Remove _static_ from the method declaration

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Steve, I removed it and now when I call the method, I get the same error. Added code above for where that is happening.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Now it seems that you are calling an instance method without having an instance of _MainWindow_ MainWindow is the name of the class not a variable of type MainWindow.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I don't understand the distinction. I have called methods from other classes present in the code already such as "LogWriters.WriteEmptyFileLog(filePath)". Can I not call "OutputBoxUpdater" from the MainWindow class in the same manner?
Perhaps there is some fundamental I am missing...

Comment: No, you can't without creating an instance of MainWindow. (You can call static methods but we already know that we can't have those methods work on non-static elements of the class) See how do you initialize an instance of a PdfDocument or FileInfo. the same should happen for MainWindow. It is a class so you want to create an instance of this class

Comment: With `LogWriters.WriteEmptyFileLog(filePath)`, you have a "utility function". You don't need an instance of the `LogWriters` class because you only ever need one of them. Since `MainForm` is a FORM there could be many instances (copies) visible at the same time. Each copy has its own distinct copies of everything (controls within it, like your RichTextBox). You must reference a specific instance of MainForm, so that it can update the specific RichTextBox within it. When you declare `OutputBoxUpdater` as static it belongs to all instances of MainForm, so it doesn't know which RTB to use.

Comment: Cool. So I have to initialize another instance of MainWindow to write to a rich text box within the new instance of it? Why can I not just write to the one that is already present in the window that opens when the application starts?  How do I reference this particular instance?

Comment: No, you don't need another instance, you need to PASS AN INSTANCE of your CURRENT FORM to the `TryToOpenPDF()` method so it can tell that specific instance to update its RTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `OutputBoxUpdater()` so it is **NOT** static:

```
public void OutputBoxUpdater(string message, Color color)
{  
    SearchRunOutputBox.SuspendLayout();
    SearchRunOutputBox.SelectionColor = color;
    SearchRunOutputBox.AppendText(message);
    SearchRunOutputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    SearchRunOutputBox.ScrollToCaret();
    SearchRunOutputBox.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Then change the signature of `TryToOpenPDF()` to receive `MainForm` as a parameter so you can use it:

```
public void TryToOpenPDF(string filePath, MainForm mf) {

    // ... code ...

    mf.OutputBoxUpdater(filePath + " successfully opened!", Color.Black);

    // ... code ...
}
```

Note that I'm using the parameter name `mf`, and not the name of the Form itself.

Somewhere in `MainForm`, you are presumably calling `TryToOpenPDF()` but you haven't shown that yet.

It'd look something like:

```
// ... within MainForm code ...

PDFOpenToCheck pdf = new PDFOpenToCheck();
pdf.TryToOpenPDF("some file path", this);
```

Note we are passing the current instance of `MainForm`, the one that is already visible, via `this`!

--- Edit ---

So you now you have to make a choice, pass the reference first to `TraverseTree()`, which then passes it on to `TryToOpenPDF()`, or CHEAT with:

```
MainForm mf = Application.OpenForms.Cast<MainForm>().Where(x => (x is MainForm)).FirstOrDefault();
if (mf != null)
{
    // ... do something with "mf" ...
}
```

Note that this assumes there will only ever be ONE instance of MainForm. This approach is generally frowned upon, though...

Comment: THANK YOU! This was much easier to understand.
And a big thanks to the others who commented as well, now that I figured it out, everything you guys said made a whooooole bunch more sense.
Cheers.

Comment: See edit at the bottom. I think you figured out what needs to be done, but I gave you an alternate approach. It's okay to "cheat" after you first understand the correct approach, and the limitations of the cheating approach.

Comment: Dope! I'll play around with that. I really appreciate your help!